# How can I reiterate a sum of values without getting my variable reassigned in a oop

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

```
def orders():
    orders= {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
    }
    while True:
        try:
            key = input("Item: ").title().lstrip().rstrip()
            total = orders[key]
            print(total , "$", sep = "")
        except KeyError:
            pass
        except EOFError:
            print("",end="\n")
            break
```

I want to reitarate a sum of total values but it keeps getting reassigned in my while loop, how can I make it store the values of the prices without breaking my loop?

Answer (score 0):

The value of total keeps getting reassigned in the while loop because that's what you told it to do:

```
total = orders[key]
```

This reassigns `total` to a new value, and forgets whatever value it had before.

If you want to actually add up all the numbers, use `+=` instead of `=`.

```
total = 0
while True:
    key = input("Item: ").title().lstrip().rstrip()
    total += orders[key]
```

Comment: I tried doing that but what I failed to understand was creating a global variable "total = 0 " to avoid giving me an error. thanks for that tip!